# How to save a image from image picker in flutter in two different size

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-image

I am working in a code to pick a image using device camera and store in a variable. I worked with saving the original photo but in the same place i also need to save the photo but with small resolution so that i can use it as thumbnail.
I need to upload both the image to firebase storage and retrieve it when needed.

```
Future getImage() async{
var tempImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera,imageQuality: 30);

setState(() {
  sampleImage=tempImage;
  _tempThumb=Image.file(sampleImage,height: 20,width: 20,);


});
}
```

My code works for storing image in tempImage variable but dont know how to upload the small image stored in _tempThumb variable

```
final StorageReference postImageRef= FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("Post Images");

    var timeKey=new DateTime.now();
    final StorageUploadTask uploadTask=postImageRef.child(timeKey.toString()+".jpg").putFile(sampleImage);


    var ImageUrl = await(await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
```

I am able to upload the full sized image but have no idea about how to upload the small sized image.

Comment: it may helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701654/how-can-i-read-from-disk-and-resize-an-image-in-flutter-dart and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542155/how-to-change-a-image-file-to-thumbnail-while-keeping-original-file-in-flutter

Comment: Hello i have seen those question and solution but sadly didnt help me out on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `pubspec.yaml`:

`image: ^2.1.4`

Add this import statement:

`import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;`

Then first decode your image:

`img.Image image = img.decodeImage(tempImage.readAsBytesSync());`

Then resize it:

`img.Image thumbnail = img.copyResize(image, width: 20, height: 20);`

Then encode it again:

`var thumb = img.encodePng(thumbnail);`

This gives an int array that you can save to firebase.